# How to protect your github code against being used for llm training

Tags: operating-system, licensing, large-language-model

The recent rise of LLMs trained on vast amounts of data, including OS repositories, leads to a licensing question.

Suppose you are OK for other human developers to build on your code but do not want to allow the likes of OpenAI to use your code for training their next GPT model. To me, it seems that the best-known existing licenses (GNU, MIT, etc.) do not cover this scenario.

Are there any out-of-the-box licenses for this scenario?